# g23 socket and 11W UV-C bulb

Tags: mains, light, uv

because UV-C machines tend to be expensive, our lab working on biological/biochemical research has reverted to attempting to build a machine from scratch.

Therefore, we recently purchased a [G23 socket](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00ZV0R8QI/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) and a [Phillips 11W UV-C bulb](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B001VTPDX8/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). Ideally, I would like to be able to make use of an IEC socket in this system, and just simply plug the machine into the wall when we need it for experiments.

Of course I would like to do this as safely as possible. I have found bits and pieces of information around, but no concrete guide.

Any advice about how to minimally and safely connect the pieces is very helpful.

Comment: You need to shop for a ballast with output 54V 0.34A

Comment: thanks. because of the wattage from the bulb?

Comment: Yes also with more bulbs and multiple output ballast e.g (quad) then ring lugs to screws or twisted wire

Answer (score 2):

You can use any fixture designed for the same type of 11W bulb, with a built-in ballast.

The UVC bulb is quite different in that it has a quartz envelope rather than glass and lacks the phosphor coating of lamps designed for lighting, but *electrically* it is identical to an 11W white bulb.

A few years ago, you would have been able to walk into (say) Ikea and get such a thing incredibly cheaply, however new CFL fixtures have been phased out in favor of LED bulbs so you may have to exercise some ingenuity.

Edit: I see plenty of them on eBay, for example, some look dubious others, less so.

[image]